# Complicated aggregation of DataFrame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, aggregation

I have DataFrame like below:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"VALUE" : [100, 200, 100, 300, 500],
                   "PRODUCT_ID" : [599, 200, 599, 599, 200],
                   "STATUS" : ["active", "active", "not_active", "unknown", "active"], 
                   "CLIENT" : ["1", "1", "2", "2", "1"]})
```

And I need to calculate *average*, *median* and *max* `VALUE` per `PRODUCT_ID` with "active" `STATUS` for each `CLIENT`. I need df something like this:

`AVG = 266,6` because of: (500+200+100) : 3

`MED = 200` ?

`MAX = 500` because of 500 is the biggest value on active aggrement for client 1

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
(df.query('STATUS=="active"')
        .groupby(['CLIENT'])['VALUE']
        .agg(['mean','median','max'])
        .reindex(df.CLIENT.unique())
     )
```

Output:

```
              mean  median    max
CLIENT                           
1       266.666667   200.0  500.0
2              NaN     NaN    NaN
```

Comment: OK, but is it possible to take also into consideration client 2 which do not have active status and give him NaN ?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
  df[df['STATUS'] == 'active'].groupby(['PRODUCT_ID', 'CLIENT']).agg(['mean','median','max'])
```

The output:

```
                 VALUE
                 mean   median  max
         PRODUCT_ID CLIENT          
          200       1   350 350 500
          599       1   100 100 100
```

Comment: What value did you add to the other answer?

Comment: The original question asks three stats per PRODUCT_ID. I do not see Quang's answer has grouping by PRODUCT_ID. My be I did not understand the question?